# NullPointerException MainFragment facebook login

Tags: java, android, facebook

Pretty new to this. I am trying to make a simple facebook login app that once logged in show a few basic user details. When I try to run the app I get the message 'Unfortunately FacebookTest has stopped'. I seem to be getting a NullPointerException but can't for the life of me work out why. Here is my logcat output:

```
03-25 12:01:16.850      919-919/com.example.robert.facebooktest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.robert.facebooktest, PID: 919
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.robert.facebooktest.MainFragment$2.onCompleted(MainFragment.java:87)
        at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:283)
        at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1668)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is as follows:

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.robert.facebooktest;

            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private MainFragment mainFragment;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
                mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
            } else {
                // Or set the fragment from restored state info
                mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
            }
        }
    }
```

MainFragment.java

```
    package com.example.robert.facebooktest;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.facebook.Request;
    import com.facebook.Response;
    import com.facebook.Session;
    import com.facebook.SessionState;
    import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
    import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
    import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView name;
        TextView location;
        TextView gender;

        private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
        // Create, automatically open (if applicable), save, and restore the
        // Active Session in a way that is similar to Android UI lifecycles.
        private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
        private View otherView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // To maintain FB Login session
            uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
            uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
            // Looks for Login button
            LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
            authButton.setFragment(this);
            // Set View that should be visible after log-in invisible initially
            otherView = view.findViewById(R.id.other_views);
            otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status","email","user_birthday"));
            return view;
        }

        // Called when session changes
        private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                             Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
            }
        };

        // When session is changed, this method is called from callback method
        private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {

            final TextView name = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
            final TextView gender = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gender);
            final TextView location = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.location);

            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
                // make request to the /me API to get Graph user
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user
                    // object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            // Set view visibility to true
                            otherView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // Set User name
                            name.setText("Hello " + user.getName());
                            // Set Gender
                            gender.setText("Your Gender: "
                                    + user.getProperty("gender").toString());
                            location.setText("Your Current Location: "
                                    + user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString());
                        }else{
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
                otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "OnActivityResult...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            uiHelper.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            uiHelper.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            uiHelper.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.robert.facebooktest.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/voyager_logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/other_views"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fb_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Kesh1234 line 87 is location.setText("Your Current Location: " +        + user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString()); in MainFragment.java

Comment: Check the value of user, location by using Log statements.

Comment: Add log statement before line 87 and check the values.

Answer (score 0):

Which is the line no 87 exactly? Somewhere in onCompleted()

Comment: line 87 is location.setText("Your Current Location: " +        + user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString()); in MainFragment.java

Comment: Make sure that getProperty("name") does not return null